# TimeZone with Calendar confusing results

Tags: java, timezone

I have been working with timezone conversions lately and am quite astonished by the result i get.Basically, i want to convert a date from one timezone into another. below is the code, conversions working fine, but what i have observed while debugging is, the date is not converted unless i call `Calendar#get(Calendar.FIELD)`.

```
    private static void convertTimeZone(String date, String time, TimeZone fromTimezone, TimeZone toTimeZone){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(fromTimezone);
        String[] dateSplit = null;
        String[] timeSplit = null;
        if(time !=null){
            timeSplit = time.split(":");
        }
        if(date!=null){
            dateSplit = date.split("/");
        }
        if(dateSplit !=null){
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]));
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1])-1);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]));
        }
        if(timeSplit !=null){
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]));

        }
//      System.out.println("Time in " + fromTimezone.getDisplayName() + " : " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) +"/"+ (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+ cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" " + ((cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<10) ? ("0"+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ): (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)))
//              +":" + (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)<10 ? "0"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) : cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) );
        cal.setTimeZone(toTimeZone);
        System.out.println("Time in " + toTimeZone.getDisplayName() + " : " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) +"/"+ (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+ cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" " + ((cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<10) ? ("0"+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ): (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)))
                +":" + (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)<10 ? "0"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) : cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) );
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        convertTimeZone("23/04/2013", "23:00", TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST5EDT"), TimeZone.getTimeZone("GB"));
    }
```

**Expected Output:** `Time in Greenwich Mean Time : 24/4/2013 04:00`

**Output i got when i comment sysout 1:** `Time in Greenwich Mean Time : 23/4/2013 23:00`

If i un-comment sysout1 i get the expected valid output.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `cal.setTimeZone()` is called after the first `SOUT`, maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: @MrD Date frist is in timezone `EST5EDT` i.e., before first sysout. I have to convert this date into GMT. thus i set the timezone(GB) after the first sysout.

Comment: @MrD As i said in the question, conversion works fie when i un-comment First Sysout. :)

Comment: try uncommenting the first `SysOut` and moving `cal.setTimeZone()` before both, see what are the outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal representation of the given date is not evaluated until really needed, that is until you try to access it by those getters.  However the best way of parsing dates is through SimpleDateFormat.

---

**EDIT** (added for summarize the comments below and to better clarify my answer).

Calendar works this way for better efficiency: instead of recalculate everithing each time you call a setter, it waits until you call a getter.

Calendar should be used mainly for date calculations (see [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) and [`roll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29)), but you are using it for parsing and formatting: these tasks are better accomplished with SimpleDateFormat, that's why I say that your usage of Calendar is not elegant.

See this example:

```
private static void convertTimeZone(String date, String time,
            TimeZone fromTimezone, TimeZone toTimeZone) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    df.setTimeZone(fromTimezone);
    Date d = df.parse(date + " " + time);
    df.setTimeZone(toTimeZone);
    System.out.println("Time in " + toTimeZone.getDisplayName() + " : " +
                       df.format(d));
}
```

I have reimplemented your method using SimpleDateFormat only.  My method is smaller, there is no splitting logic (it's hidden in `parse()`), and also the output is handled in a simpler way.  Furthermore the date format is expressed in a compact and standard way that can be easily internationalized using a ResourceBundle.

Also note that the timezone conversion is just a formatting task: the internal representation of the parsed date does **not** change.

Comment: Can you describe exactly [why not](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar)?

Comment: Well, the point is it should give me the appropriate date time after converting the timezone. i.e., why is it needed to call Calendar#get(Fields) twice?? once before i convert and once after i convert ?

Comment: For better efficiency: instead of recalculate everithing each time you call a setter, it waits until you call a getter. The way you are using Calendar is not elegant, I recommend you to use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @Pino AFAIK, SimpleDateFormat is used for formatting your dates. I need to do timezone convertion. can you be specific why this approch is not an elegant way ??

Comment: tbh I think this qualifies as a bug, `setTimeZone()` doesn't recalculate the fields, it just sets `areAllFieldsSet` to false, which is riddiculous as `.get` doesn't check for that. Just look at the link I posted

Comment: @MrD thanks, yeah, you are probably right. i am currently checking the source myself :)

Comment: The name of the method is setTimeZone not convertTimeZone.  No bug, IMHO.

Comment: @Pino I have looked at the source, and the issue is Calendar#set(Field) doesn't set the flags to true, When you call Calendar#get(Field) for the first time, it updates the state and the flags. thus, the changes are reflected on the next cal to Calendar#get(Field). Is this what you mean in your answer ?. BTW, can you clarify why it is not elegant to use Calendar for timezone conversion ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is partly explained in [a commented section in `setTimeZone()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29):

> *Consider the sequence of calls: cal.setTimeZone(EST); cal.set(HOUR, 1); cal.setTimeZone(PST).
>   Is cal set to 1 o'clock EST or 1 o'clock PST?  Answer: PST.  More
>   generally, a call to setTimeZone() affects calls to set() BEFORE AND
>   AFTER it up to the next call to complete().*

In other words, the sequence

1. Set Calendar time
2. Change TimeZone

is interpreted to mean "Use this time in this new time zone", while the sequence

1. Set Calendar time
2. Get the time (or some part of it)
3. Change Time Zone

will be interpreted as "Use this time in the old time zone, then change it".

So, in your case, to get the behavior you are hoping for, you will need to call `get()`, or any other method that internally calls `complete()` inside the `Calendar`, before you change the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted to using TimeZone and Calendar? If not I suggest using the excellent Library [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which makes handling time zones much easier.

Your example would then look like this:

```
public static void convertTimeZoneJoda(String date, String time, DateTimeZone fromTimezone, DateTimeZone toTimeZone) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm").withZone(fromTimezone);
    DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(date+time).withZone(toTimeZone);

    System.out.println("Time in " + toTimeZone.getID() + " : " + dt.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    convertTimeZoneJoda("23/04/2013", "23:00", DateTimeZone.forID("EST5EDT"), DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
}
```

JodaTime also allows for convenient conversation between TimeZone and DateTimeZone.

Comment: unfortunately, yes i am restricted to use only TimeZone and calendar. As you can see its a simple timezone conversion. so basic Calendar and TimeZOne API should do it. i dunno where i am doing wrong though :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to [@Pino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685806/pino)'s answer, the reason why `get()` doesn't return an updated time is because `setTimeZone()` simply doesn't update the fields, just sets `areAllFieldsSet` to false, which is useless since `get()` doesn't check for it. If you ask me, this is very poorly coded from SUN's part. Here is the competent code from [`Calendar`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar):

**`setTimeZone()`**:

```
    public void  setTimeZone(TimeZone value){
        zone = value;
        sharedZone = false;
        areAllFieldsSet = areFieldsSet = false;

    }
```

**`get()`**:

```
protected final int internalGet(int field){
    return fields[field];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to convert to UTC:

1. create a Calendar Object with UTC time zone

   ```
   Calendar utcTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
   ```
2. set the point in time in the UTC Calendar object from the "any time zone" Calendar object

   ```
   utcTime.setTimeInMillis(myCalendarObjectInSomeOtherTimeZone.getTimeInMillis());
   ```
3. `utcTime` will now contain the same point in time as `myCalendarObjectInSomeOtherTimeZone` converted to UTC.